# Spring Batch 5.0 - How can we use it without persisting meta data to DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Run the Spring batch application giving the below exception, how can I avoid the metadata config

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:101) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1538) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=H000.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE, DRIVER=4.31.10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Use an in-memory database like H2, HSQLDB, etc and configure the JDBC `JobRepository` implementation provided by Spring Batch to use it
- Implement the `JobRepository` interface the way you want to handle meta-data and configure Spring Batch to use your custom implementation

Comment: Could you please provide an example, how to implement JobRepository for Postgres.